# HAProxy mixture of wildcard and specific url's to different backends

Tags: haproxy

I have the following two frontend configuration statements in HAProxy.

```
acl auth_domain hdr(host) -m reg -i ^auth\.web\.simoncarr\.co\.uk$
acl k8s_domain hdr(host) -m reg -i ^[^\.]+\.web\.simoncarr\.co\.uk$
```

The first line checks for the specific domain `auth.web.simoncarr.co.uk`, the second checks for `*.web.simoncarr.co.uk`

Individually they both work fine, but I if both are included and no matter what order, the wildcard always wins.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by editing my wild card as below.

```
acl k8s_domain hdr(host) -m reg -i ^(?!auth)[^\.]+\.web\.simoncarr\.co\.uk$
```